# TFDQuery parameter by index is different than by name

Tags: delphi, firedac

```
q: TFDQuery;
```

Watches:

```
q.Params[166].Name     = 'date'
q.Params[166].Value    = Null
q.ParamByName('date').Value = '21.07.1902 02:24:03'
q.Params.ParamByName('date').Value = '21.07.1902 02:24:03'
```

Why I get different results when referencing parameters directly and through `ParamByName` ?

Comment: Possibly because when translated to a date in this database zero is '21.07.1902 02:24:03'?

Comment: It is not saved into database yet. It is an in-memory object.

Comment: I don't follow what you are intending to show with your watches.  Are you saying that the Watch window is displaying the `q.Params[166]` entries simultaneously with one another?  And simultaneously with the other two?  Does the `166` serious mean that you have 166+ parameters defined?  I think this is a case where a screen-shot might help clarify your point.

Comment: Perhaps there is a second parameter named 'date'? As the server uses the index anyway, it doesn't bother if you name two parameters the same.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe: Yes, Uwe. Thank you. I have two date parameters: `DATE` and `date`.